# Can Timemachine restore the backup of an external drive to another external drive?

Tags: macos, time-machine

I have two external drives attaching to my Mac, one for file storage and one for time machine. The latter one keeps the TM backups of the former one. If someday I lost the former one is it possible that I could just buy a new drive and restore the data back to the new drive easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Enter Time Machine, select the item to be restored, then press control and select "Restore" from the on-screen button. You'll be presented a finder window in which to select the restore destination. More at [Pondini](http://pondini.org/TM/16.html).

Comment: Thank you David, I just can’t make the comfirmation when it comes to external drive.

Comment: If the external disk target doesn't show up in the Finder, make sure your Mac's Finder > Preferences > Sidebar has the "External Disk" box checked.